# How does Rails Magic work with connecting the right js files to the right .html.erb

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, erb

I have a `.js` file named:

`app/assets/javascripts/generics/directory/edit_person.js`

that isn't included in the `application.js` because there's not\ `require_tree` and looking at the network tab in the browser, I've confirmed the `edit_person.js` is being served by itself.

The `erb` being rendered is named:

`app/views/company_area/directory/edit_person.html.erb`

I don't see any script tags in here referencing `edit_person.js`, is there some magic that Rails is doing?

Comment: I think you might be talking about controller specific assets - https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#controller-specific-assets

Comment: Make sure the js isn't being called from the application/layouts view file either.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to show us the relevant code.

A Rails application typically will serve JS in one of three circumstances:

1. A JS file is specified in your html. This includes application.js in the layout file.
2. A JS *request* was made and you are responding to that JS. Example: the JS file edit_person.js exists in the views folder corresponding to the controller action `edit_person` and a client makes a .js request to that action
3. Webpacker is configured to handle JS alongside the asset pipeline. [1]

If none of these apply to you, then you will not see your JS loading on the page. Knowing that, you need to check your layout, application.js, and controller actions (responses).

[1] *Webpacker would not likely be serving these files due to their location in your dirs, but it was worth noting for the sake of accuracy.*

Answer (score 0):

is this an app you wrote? If not I would check any of the layout files (particularly: views/layouts/application.html.erb or views/layouts/persons.html.erb if available )